# Why my woocommerce pagination arguments don't update?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, woocommerce

```
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
<?php
    echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array(
        'base'         => esc_url( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) ),
        'format'       => '',
        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
        'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text'    => '&larr;',
        'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
        'type'         => 'list',
        'end_size'     => 3,
        'mid_size'     => 3
    ) ) );
?>
```

This is the woocommerce pagination arguments in woocommerce/templates/loop/pagination.php. It should be simple to change 'prev_text' and 'next_text' but it doesn't work for me. I want to change them to < and >. Tried clearing browser cache, make the change even in the plugin itself, still the same ← arrows appear.

Any idea what I could be missing?

Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you showed your own code, instead of the default plugin code.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with following:

```
'prev_text'    => '&lt;',
'next_text'    => '&gt;',
```

Comment: Thanks but still nothing, will see what woocommerce has to say about this